# Trouble creating properly aligned matrix within a matrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, matrices

I'm trying to insert parentheses around a group of elements creating a matrix within a larger matrix. So far I have this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \omega_0 \\
-\omega_0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix} &
\begin{matrix}
-\frac{p_1}{2} & -\frac{p_2}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{p_2}{2} \\
-\frac{p_2}{2} & \frac{p_1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix} & \omega_0 \mathbf{I}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{yx} & (I_{yy} - I_{zz}) & 2 I_{yz} \\
(I_{zz} - I_{xx}) & -I_{xy} & -2 I_{xz} \\
-I_{yz} & I_{xz} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Basically, it's four smaller matrices combined into one larger one. However, the elements aren't aligned between these matrices. Sorry there's no picture, I don't have the reputation yet to include one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :). As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Are seven rows on the left side and only six on the right side correct?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}

Original:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \omega_0 \\
-\omega_0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix} &
\begin{matrix}
-\frac{p_1}{2} & -\frac{p_2}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{p_2}{2} \\
-\frac{p_2}{2} & \frac{p_1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix} & \omega_0 \mathbf{I}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{yx} & (I_{yy} - I_{zz}) & 2 I_{yz} \\
(I_{zz} - I_{xx}) & -I_{xy} & -2 I_{xz} \\
-I_{yz} & I_{xz} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Revised:

\def\x{\begin{array}{c} x\\x\\x\end{array}}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ -\omega_0 \\ 0 \\0 \\0 \\0 \\
\end{array}
 &
\begin{array}{c@{\hspace{0ex}}}
0 \\ \omega_0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \\0 \\0 \\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{0ex}}c}
 \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \omega_0 \mathbf{I}^{-1} \\ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{0ex}}c@{\hspace{0ex}}}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \scalerel*[1.8ex]{(}{\x} \\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{0ex}}c}
-p_1/2 \\ 0 \\ -p_2/2 \\ \\ I_{yx} \\(I_{zz} - I_{xx}) \\ -I_{yz} \\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
-p_2/2 \\ 0 \\ p_1/2 \\ \\ (I_{yy} - I_{zz}) \\ -I_{xy} \\ -I_{xz} \\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c@{\hspace{0ex}}}
0 \\p_2/2 \\ 0 \\ \\ 2I_{yz} \\ -2I_{xz} \\ 0 \\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{0ex}}c@{\hspace{0ex}}}
\\ \\ \\ \\ \scalerel*[1.8ex]{)}{\x} \\
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As egreg pointed out, I am indeed missing a row in the top right quadrant, but the solution provided by Mr. Segletes should do the trick with a little modification!