# How to define the proper space between elements of a matrix?

Tags: spacing, matrices

I need to draw a simple matrix, with column corresponding to some sets. I tried the following:

```
\[D^{4}_{2}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
       \diagdown & {\begin{array}{cccccc} \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{1,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{3,4\} \end{array}} \\ 
      {\begin{array}{c} 
     \{1,2\} \\
     \{1,3\} \\
     \{2,3\} \\
     \{1,4\} \\
     \{2,4\} \\
     \{3,4\}
      \end{array}} & 
      {\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\   
         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right)}
\end{array}\right] 
\]
```

which resulted with:
[image: matrix with titles]

how can I space out the inner matrix elements, so it would fit the rows and columns of the entire table?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i don't have the package `scalerel`, and i'm googling right now on how to add a package, but since i need to distribute the lines evenly, and not like the example you linked to, isn't there a better way to do so?

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106563/trouble-creating-properly-aligned-matrix-within-a-matrix/106573#106573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible way; `\overmat` writes its first argument above the entries enclosed in the second argument; the separation between columns in the inner matrix was increased using `10pt` for `arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\overmat[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{$\smash{\color{white}\overbrace{\vphantom{%
    \begin{matrix}{c}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\mkern12mu \text{\color{black}#1}}}$}#2}

\newcommand\diagdown{}% temporal definition

\begin{document}

\[D^{4}_{2}=
\left[\begin{array}{c@{}c} 
       \diagdown &  \\ 
      {\begin{array}{>{\scriptstyle}c}
     \{1,2\} \\
     \{1,3\} \\
     \{2,3\} \\
     \{1,4\} \\
     \{2,4\} \\
     \{3,4\}
      \end{array}} &
    \setlength\arraycolsep{10pt} 
      {\left(\begin{array}{@{\mkern5mu}cccccc@{\mkern5mu}}
         \overmat{\{1,2\}}{0} & \overmat{\{1,3\}}{0} 
           & \overmat{\{2,3\}}{0} & \overmat{\{1,4\}}{0} 
           & \overmat{\{2,4\}}{0} & \overmat{\{3,4\}}{1} \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\   
         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right)}
\end{array}\right] 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since I didn't know the definition of `\diagdown`, I provided a partial definition `\newcommand\diagdown{}`. Use your actual definition in your document.

Comment: thanks! it is exactly what i needed :) BTW, diagdown is a symbol... i didn't define anything... it's just the backslash like character in the corner...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a second answer using `kbordermatrix` - perhaps not what you want now, but a nice tool to know about. (Get `kbordermatrix.sty` from http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/generic/misc/kbordermatrix.sty if necessary.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\kbordermatrix{
& \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{2,3\} & \{1,4\} & \{2,4\} & \{3,4\} \\
 \{1,2\} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \{1,3\} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \{2,3\} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\   
 \{1,4\} &  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \{2,4\} &  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \{3,4\} &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0           
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the version using `scalerel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}


\setlength\arraycolsep{.5ex}
\def\x{\begin{array}{c} x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\end{array}}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
\\ \{1,2\} \\ \{1,3\} \\ \{2,3\} \\ \{1,4\} \\ \{2,4\} \\ \{3,4\}
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
 \\ \scalerel*[1.2ex]{(}{\x}
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{1,2\} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{1,3\} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{2,3\} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{1,4\} \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{2,4\} \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
\{3,4\} \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\\
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c}
 \\ \scalerel*[1.2ex]{)}{\x}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't upload PDF file to imgur, because they are converted to a very low resolution PNG; prefer a PNG file that you can obtain in various ways (check the `standalone` class, for instance). I usually do a screen capture.

Comment: @egreg I did not intend to upload PDF, but jpg.  Must have inadvertantly typed or clicked the wrong file.  Thanks for the heads up.